# Вызов нужного поля из класса через параметр метода

Tags: c#, массивы, словари

Нужно, чтобы переменная result имела значение 5

```
public class Test : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        private int v1 { get; set; }
        private int v2 { get; set; }
        private int v3 { get; set; }
        private int v4 { get; set; }

        [Command("tst")]
        public async Task Tst(int ItemId)
        {
            var m = new Test();

            m.v1 = 1;
            m.v2 = 1;
            m.v3 = 1;
            m.v4 = 1;

            int[] nums = new int[] { m.v1, m.v2, m.v3, m.v4 };

            nums[ItemId] = 5;

            var result = m.v3;

            await ReplyAsync($"{result}");
               
        }
    }
```

Comment: предположу, что у вас именно поля, не св-ва. в чём проблема создать массив (если потребуется, ассоциативный), и хранить в нём названия полей/`FiledInfo`? пример: `var fields = (new[] { "Water", "Bucket", ... }).Select(name => typeof(InventoryUser).GetField(name)).ToArray()` (можно реализовать через цикл). `var item = fields[itemId - 1].GetValue(invUser)`.

Comment: @return да фишка в том, что если я всё это дело буду делать через массив, то я получу значение поля, а мне нужно присвоить другое значение

Comment: @return А стоп видимо до меня дошло

Comment: @return щас попробую)

Comment: `fields[itemId - 1].SetValue(invUser, ...)`

Comment: Кстати, уточните: у вас действительно **поля** или **свойства**?

Comment: @return  Всё изменил свой вопрос на корректный.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov  Всё изменил свой вопрос на корректный.

Comment: Сейчас вопрос стал намного хуже. В такой постановке вместо приватных(!) свойств(!) достаточно иметь массив.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov извиняюсь но я думаю, суть я донес, что нужно чтобы переменная result была 5

Comment: Я лишь повторю, что первая версия вопроса имела смысл. Эта версия - нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov у меня поля в прошлом примере это столбцы из базы данных, мне нужно решение в таком виде в котором я приподнес, я тоже могу решить данный пример через массив

Comment: Мне кажется у вас изначально неверная архитектура проекта. Задайте себе как минимум простой вопрос: Ваш метод `Tst` точно должен знать про все свойства класса? Или он отвечает за что-то одно? Например, в вашей первой ревизии вопроса у вас есть `Вода`, `Ведро`, `Ведро с водой`, `Почва`, `Доски`, вот вам уже не кажется тут странным все это? Почему допустим "ведро" и "ведро с водой" это разные значения? При чем здесь почва и доски? Почему вода отдельно? Если это просто предметы в инвентаре игрока, то почему они у вас идут как полноценные столбцы в базе, а не как "предмет в инвентаре с кол-вом"?

Comment: Я на вашем месте сделал коллекцию предметов `public List<Item> Items..`, в которой хранил нужные предметы простым `Items.Add(new Water())` или `Items.Add(new Bucket(){IsEmpty = false, Count = 10} )`, заметьте, предмет, это отдельный класс, со своими свойствами, значениями и др. Вы получаете больше возможностей для расширения, чем просто циферки. А если вам надо получить общее число, то считайте `var count = Items.Count(x=>x is Water)`. Ну если вы так хотите держать в виде отдельных столбиков в базе, то самое простое, что я бы вам подсказал, [это](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N4BbW1).

Comment: Ну а еще лучше, разделил бы это на отдельные методы, отдельные органы управления (допустим `.AddWater(5)`), ибо помним про вопрос "а должен ли метод знать про все значения?", я предполагаю, что нет, метод работы с досками не должен знать что-либо про воду, это не его ответственность. Можем пойти дальше, расширить это, мы получим не `int Water`, а `Water Water`, то есть делаем отдельный класс, который будет иметь `int Value` и методы `.Add(int count)` `.Take(int count)` и др.  Сейчас же вы все месите в одну кучу, что очень плохо.

Comment: Просто оставьте вариант с несколькими `if`, как было сделано изначально. Просто и понятно. / Возможно, вы изобретаете `DataTable`: в нём можно обращаться к колонкам как по имени, так и по индексу. А ещё его можно сделать типизированным.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да ваш модель реализации для меня новая и интересная возьму на вооружение, но она далеко от моего большого количества if не ушла мне просто важно написать данный код красиво, а не на каком-то базовом уровне

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашему решению, вам нужно менять значение свойство. И вы хотите при вызове метода как-то задать, какое именно свойство.

Можно определить метод следующим образом:

```
public async Task PutUpForSale(Action<InventoryUser> action)
{
    var invUser = InventoryUserDb.GetInventoryUser(Context.User.Id, Context.Guild.Id);

    action(invUser);

    await InventoryUserDb.SetInventoryUser(invUser);
}
```

Желаемая операция передаётся в виде делегата.
Использование:

```
await PutUpForSale(user => user.Bucket -= quantity);
```

Достоинство: вместо номера свойства (которое может измениться при добавлении новых или удалении старых свойств) указывается непосредственно его имя.

Недостаток: можно по ошибке задать неверную операцию. Например: `user.Bucket *= quantity` - умножение вместо вычитания.

---

Предложу ещё одно решение.

Используем структуру с явным размещением полей. И буфер фиксированного размера.

При этом необходимо разрешить небезопасный код.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Test
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] private int v1;
    [FieldOffset(4)] private int v2;
    [FieldOffset(8)] private int v3;
    [FieldOffset(12)] private int v4;

    [FieldOffset(0)] private unsafe fixed int vs[4];

    public void Tst(int itemId)
    {
        var m = new Test();

        m.v1 = 1;
        m.v2 = 1;
        m.v3 = 1;
        m.v4 = 1;

        unsafe
        {
            m.vs[itemId] = 5;
        }

        int result = m.v3;
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Достоинства: работает быстро, нет лишнего расхода памяти.

Недостатки: нельзя использовать класс, необходим unsafe.

Comment: мне кажется ответ немного не по теме. задача автора была получить предмет по его id, вы же отклонились от первоначальной идеи

Comment: @return - Судя по решению автора, ему нужно изменять значение свойства. А свойство нужно как-то указать при вызове метода. Вариант с делегатом вместо нумерации свойств использует само свойство.

Comment: Частично согласен с @return. Автор просит по itemId применять нужный Action к классу. Ваш ответ очень легко доработать до того, что хочет автор, используя заранее определенный словарь `Dictionary<int, Action<InventoryUser>>`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko - тогда придётся определить этот словарь и поддерживать его корректность в процессе изменения кода (добавление-удаление свойств).